# Exact match multiple words in regex (datatables)

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I'm trying to create a regex search in Datatables which matches a user who belongs to all selected groups.

Example:

User A belongs to **Users**, **Other**, **Other Users**

User B belongs to **Users**, **Other**

If **Users** and **Other Users** are selected as filters, only user A should show in the table. The problem I'm having is that both users are showing when these filters are selected. I don't think the regex is matching exact strings and, after looking through multiple other answers, I don't seem to be able to get it to do so.

My solution:

```
if (!this.items.length) {
    table.column(i).search('');
} else {
    let regex = '^';

    this.items.forEach(v => regex += `(?=.*\\b${v}\\b)`);

    regex += '.*$'

    table.column(i).search(regex, true, false, true)
}
```

Which results in: `^(?=.*\bUsers\b)(?=.*\bOther Users\b).*$`

However, the user belonging to **Users**,**Other** is still being returned.

Comment: Try this: `this.items.forEach(v => regex += "(?=.*(?<!\\S)${v}(?!\\S))");`

Comment: It must be `this.items.forEach(v => regex += "(?=.*(?<![^,])${v}(?![^,]))");` or - if lookbehinds are not supported - `this.items.forEach(v => regex += "(?=.*(?:[^,]|^)${v}(?![^,]))");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked! Is it possible for you to post an answer with an explanation of the regex? Would be good to understand it a little more and gives me the opportunity to mark as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce a comma or start/end of string check before and after each of your search term:

```js
this.items.forEach(v => regex += "(?=.*(?:[^,]|^)${v}(?![^,]))");
```

Or, if the JavaScript environment supports lookbehinds:

```js
this.items.forEach(v => regex += "(?=.*(?<![^,])${v}(?![^,]))");
```

The `(?:[^,]|^)` / `(?<![^,])` (equal to `(?<=,|^)`) part requires start of string position or a comma right before your search term and the `(?![^,])` negative lookahead requires a comma or end of string immediately to the right of the current position (`(?![^,])` is equal to `(?=,|$)` positive lookahead).